# Jboss server 6.x not starting

Tags: java-8, jboss6.x

I am getting following problem while starting the server jboss 6.1
I have installed jboss 6.0 and tryning to run my project but while starting the server it is showing following error.

```
13:49:31,222 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///D:/Abhishek%20Kumar/NSAP/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1496733181905/deploy/NSAP.war state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///D:/Abhishek%20Kumar/NSAP/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1496733181905/deploy/NSAP.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.8.0_121]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_121]
```

> Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: NSAP.war/WEB-INF/lib/pagination-tag-2.0.jar/META-INF/pagination.tld@12,35 seems to be the culprit. Please post the TLD.

Comment: pagination-tag-2.0.jar is the jar file

Comment: The error stems from the JSP Tag Library Definition (TLD) `pagination.tld` inside the JAR. If it is a third party JAR, then most probably some dependencies are missing.

Comment: what can i doto remove such errors

Comment: What is the source of the pagination-tag-2.0.jar?

Comment: now i have removed that file from the library because pagination-tag-3.0.jar is already available.

Comment: now i am getting following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.jms.WebservicesDescriptorProcessorImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.jms.JMSDescriptorProcessor

Comment: then how can i remove this erro sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145944/discussion-between-vivekratansinha-and-abhishek-shandilya).

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is JDK8.
JBoss 6.1.0 was tested against JDK6, not on JDK7 or JDK8.

`https://developer.jboss.org/thread/195264`

You have two options:

- Upgrade JBoss to a current and supported version
- Downgrade to JDK6

Comment: downgraded but i can not run any project in IDE eclipse neon without java 1.8